# cross-compilation FFTW for cortex-a15 failure: co-processor offset out of range

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, neon, fftw

I am trying to cross-compil FFTW 3.3.3 for cortex-a15 ARM processor with neon support but I get this error:

**/tmp/ccsNpqyK.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccsNpqyK.s:1035: Error: co-processor offset out of range**

Here is my configuration:

**./configure --prefix=/usr/fftw_3_float_neon_ARNDALE --with-slow-timer --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-float --enable-neon "CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mtune=cortex-a15 -O3 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -mvectorize-with-neon-quad -funsafe-math-optimizations"**

I tried to remove -O3 option but I got the same error.
The cross-compilation works for ARM cortex-a9.

Could anyone help me to fix that problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Guix

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off auto vectorization.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working.  The FFTW team says that is a compiler bug. I will wait for a new gcc version...